# How to publish Android app into market for particular screen resolution?

Tags: android, google-play

I have developed one android application for the devices with exact screen size of 480x800. Now i have no idea about how to publish this app for this particular screen size. If i filter by using  tag in manifest , it can accept both 480x800 (WVGA800)and 480x854 (WVGA854). But my app is suitable only for WVGA800.

Comment: You should be creating your app using relative layouts, not absolute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use "dp" (density independent pixel) instead of "px", so your app will fit on any screen size/density.

Also, take a look into the View's layout_weight XML property. It will allow you to set a view's size as 100%, for instance.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't possible. What is your app doing to make it only suitable for a single screen resolution?