# How to deploy PhoneGap App to Android TABLET Market?

Tags: cordova, google-play, tablet

I built a phonegap app that is simply an launcher to a website.  You download the app, click on it, and it will open up your web browser at a specific url.

People with android phones see this app in the Google Play market.  People with Samsung Galaxy Tab do not see this app in the Google Play Market.  How do I make this app accessible to people with Galaxy Tab?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I commented, AndroidManifest file of your app does supply information like required screen size for the app, minimum DPI, etc. You may need to set those values to match screensizes of Tablets, and then it'll show up in Play Store for tablets as well.

For more info, you may wanna look at [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/compatible-screens-element.html) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4647116/how-to-publish-android-app-into-market-for-particular-screen-resolution).

Comment: my androidmanifest file looks to be encoded in a way that's not human readable.  In phone gap framework, i can't seem to find the relevant settings to produce the right androidmanifest file i'm looking for.  So trying to build this web launching icon with native android technology now, which hopefully gives me better access to the androidmanifest file.

Comment: @John: If your webapp is using HTML5-CSS3 which is known to support well in Android's built-in browser, then instead PhoneGap, you can create native android project, have a `LinearLayout` with whole screen area taken up by `WebView`, thus it'll feel like native app but still be using your webapp within it.

Comment: for certain reasons, we just want to throw them to their web browser for now.  But that's a good tip which we'll use on future apps!  Anyway, just trying to learn all this android stuff right now.....damn this learning curve

Comment: @John: I'm currently learning Android too, while learning thoroughly with basics takes time, but for getting up and running in no time is just a series of nice [YouTube Videos](http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLD390AA9765F76D8F&feature=plcp) away!! Cheers... :)